# nextcord slash command does not register

Tags: discord, discord.py, nextcord

When moving to nextcord from discord.py the slash command is not registered.

I have enabled the `applications.command` on oauth2 URI.

```py
from nextcord import Intents
import nextcord
from nextcord.ext import commands
from nextcord import Interaction

token = "token"
Intent = Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', Intents=Intent)

@bot.slash_command(name="test", description="test", guild_ids=[myserverid])
async def test(interaction: Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("test")

bot.run(token)
```

Comment: Why are trying to move to nextcord ? discord.py support much more than slash commands.

Comment: discord.py does not support the slash command. it needs to use discord-py-slashcommand or nextcord.

Comment: discord.py master branch is supporting it now, please check this [migrating to V2](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/migrating.html)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend removing command prefix although that is optional. As for the problem, myserverid isn't defined. How is the bot supposed to know what your server is? Just define myserverid as your serverid. If you don't know how to get it, turn on developer mode, then right-click your server and copy and paste the server id. It'll look like this:

```
from nextcord import Intents
import nextcord
from nextcord.ext import commands
from nextcord import Interaction

myserverid = 1
token = "token"
Intent = Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', Intents=Intent)

@bot.slash_command(name="test", description="test", guild_ids=[myserverid])
async def test(interaction: Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("test")

bot.run(token)
```

Hope all of this helps **ツ**

Answer (score 0):

You need to add
myserverid = and add here your testing server ID
put this under bot = ...

Comment: Plz provide an example code of use that works from the context of the question.